# border-radius not working on Chrome all of sudden

Tags: google-chrome, css

Did Chrome change css rendering rule overnight?

I've noticed this morning that the border radius property is not being interpreted on Chrome all of sudden.

It works fine on IE9 & 10.  And as far as I know, below is a valid css.  I can't figure out what is going on.

```
nav[role="full-top"] ul > li:after {

  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 5em;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 0 2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

}
```

[image: rendered in Chrome]

The squares you see between links are supposed to be circles like this (as rendered in IE)

[image: rendered in IE]

You can check for yourself if you can't believe your eyes.  hackya.com

border-radius not working in Chrome?  That's just bizarre.

Comment: Its working fine for me (whether I use `%` or `em`) .. I'm on Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: works for me in Chrome as well: Version 26.0.1410.65

Comment: oops, just updated to 27.0.1453.93 and now it doesn't work...hmm

Comment: Damn!! Why is Chrome backstabbing me?  I've always liked you Chrome!!! Don't do this to me!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a width and height to your :after declaration!

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help it. Gosh, I never thought Chrome would suck like this, ever.

Comment: Browser hacked and added width:.5em and height:.5em and got the circles back. Pixel measures gave me the same result.

Comment: @Matthew for me it works by adding height **and** width. Also just updated Chrome. Weird thing.

Comment: Thanx.  That solved it.  Wow, Chrome doesn't understand px anymore?

Comment: @Matthew px works for me on both radius and width+height, looks like you need a little offset to center those circles :)

Comment: @pzin, I had added height & width in px & that didn't work.  em works.  Isn't this just bizarre?

Comment: @chrisgonzalez,thanx for spotting that 1px offset.  added 1px.:D

Comment: @Matthew, it worked for me. [I made a screenshot](http://s8.postimg.org/mkrhayahx/Captura_de_pantalla_2013_05_22_a_la_s_19_34_53.png).

Comment: @pzin, I think px works for you because you are on a Mac.  I am on a PC.  (Windows7)  I had tried the exact same code & border-radius does not work.

I am happy with em anyhow. :D  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `-webkit-border-radius` property (`-moz-border-radius` for firefox)

Comment: border-radius is now prefix-free in chrome, safari 5+, and firefox 4+!